# Alpha-Beta pruning makes minimax function return bad moves

Tags: c#, minimax

So I am working on a checkers game in c#, and have implemented a minimax function that works really well. The problem is that it takes a long time to calculate moves, so I tried implementing alpha-beta pruning. This however broke my function and now it does weird moves.

```
public double MiniMax(int depth, bool isMaxPlayer, Piece[,] tempBoard, double alpha, double beta)
        {
            int victory = CheckVictory(board, isMaxPlayer);
            if (victory == int.MaxValue)
                return double.PositiveInfinity;
            else if (victory == int.MinValue)
                return double.NegativeInfinity;
            else if (victory == 0)
                return 0;
            if (depth == 0 )
                return EvaluatePosition(board, isMaxPlayer);       

            List<Move> allLegalMoves = GetAllLegalMoves(isMaxPlayer, board);
            double bestEval = isMaxPlayer ? double.NegativeInfinity : double.PositiveInfinity;

            if (isMaxPlayer)
            {
                foreach(Move move in allLegalMoves)
                {
                    MakeMove(move, board);
                    double eval = MiniMax(depth - 1, false, board, alpha, beta);
                    UndoMove(move, board);

                    if (eval > bestEval)
                        bestEval = eval;
                    alpha = Math.Max(alpha, bestEval);
                    if (beta <= alpha)
                    {
                        break;
                    }
                }

                return bestEval;
            }
            else
            {
                foreach (Move move in allLegalMoves)
                {
                    MakeMove(move, board);
                    double eval = MiniMax(depth - 1, true, board, alpha, beta);                   
                    UndoMove(move, board);
                    if (eval <= bestEval)
                    {
                        bestEval = eval;
                        if(depth == this.depth) 
                            bestMove = move;                      
                    }
                    beta = Math.Min(beta, bestEval);
                    if (beta <= alpha)
                    {
                        break;
                    }
                }

                return bestEval;
            }
        }
```

The only thing I changed was breaking from the loop when beta <= alpha and returning alpha and beta in the different loops instead of just the 'bestEval' value.
What did I do wrong here?